# Pure php facebook sdk or facebook php sdk with javascript sdk

Tags: php, facebook

i try to find the most efficient way for Facebook connect. 
after some search i think that facebook connect with php and js sdk combined is common.

is it too much difference over the pure php sdk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With javascript sdk, you can get access token and with the function of php sdk named setaccesstoken, you can  get the user. However, in php sdk, you do all operations including getting access token in server side and this ascribe server. Php sdk with js is better.

Answer (score 0):

The reason most people split between both server and client side access is for performance. It is common to use server side access to get things you need to interact with on the server; user's information and similar, so that you can add to your database and authenticate your user. However, calls to the Facebook API are incredibly slow, therefore people often pass non-critical calls to the client side js library.